# PHP & JS - Jcrop - chosen PNG image has black background

Tags: javascript, php, image, symfony, jcrop

When I choose PNG file with transparent background in Jcrop container it is displayed with black background. When I crop it and save it, it is saved as `.png` file, but with black background as it was displayed in crop container.

JS:

```
$('#image').Jcrop({
    bgColor: 'transparent',
    aspectRatio: 1,
    minSize: [180, 180],
    maxSize: [20000, 20000],
    onSelect: updateCoords,
    onChange: updateCoords,
    boxWidth: $('.modal-body', $imageUploadModal).width()
});
```

PHP for saving images:

```
$target_w = $target_h = 400;

$src = $request->request->get('src');
$x = $request->request->get('x');
$y = $request->request->get('y');
$w = $request->request->get('w');
$h = $request->request->get('h');

ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

$img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
imagealphablending($img_r, true);

$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($target_w, $target_h);

imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, 0, 0, $x, $y, $target_w, $target_h, $w, $h);

$randomStringGenerator = new RandomStringGenerator();
$filename = '/profile-pictures/'.$randomStringGenerator->generate(50).'.png';

imagepng($dst_r, $filename);
imagedestroy($img_r);
imagedestroy($dst_r);

ini_restore('memory_limit');
```

Any ideas what I could be missing? `bgColor` as I saw in multiple answers as solution does not have any effect and is not fixing the issue.

Comment: Please make sure to **copy and paste** your code to avoid typos. Your JS is missing a quote, and is therefore invalid.

Comment: your code (with missing quote) should word  : https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/issues/13

Comment: Oh sorry idk how it got deleted by mistake, anyway this is not the problem. @DOZ 'transparent' is not working unfortunatelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because of [imagecreatetruecolor](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php)

Quoting example gave in first user contributed note on the manual page :

> If you want to create a *transparent* PNG image, where the background
>   is fully transparent, and all draw operations happen on-top of this,
>   then do the following:
>
> "Richard Davey"

```
<?php
    $png = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 600);
    imagesavealpha($png, true);

    $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($png, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($png, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

    $red = imagecolorallocate($png, 255, 0, 0);
    imagefilledellipse($png, 400, 300, 400, 300, $red);

    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($png);
?>
```

Meaning when you creatre your "host" image to copy cropped image to, you say it has a transparent background